# Standalone Opentelemetry collector coded in C#, a viable endeavour?

Tags: .net, open-telemetry

Is there any public domain C# code that illustrates how to receive Opentelemetry data
across a network connection? I have spent hours searching for such an example and the absence of example code leads me to wonder if there are hidden complexities.

I want to develop a standalone Opentelemetry program that receives OTEL traces across a network sent using the standard [OTLP protocol](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/reference/specification/protocol/).

The [.Net implementation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet) of OpenTelemetry specifies many extension points such as a Sampler and a Processor but these seem oriented to the situation where application generated tracing data is already in memory and requires custom interception prior to export across a network.

The OTLP protocol has a GRPC/Protobuf implementation so maybe the answer to my question is to find the .proto idl definition for OTLP-GRPC and let Visual Studio generate a GRPC service from that.

Edit: I found the OTLP protobuf IDL definition files in the main Opentelemetry GitHub repository here https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet) looks like a good start.

Comment: @Orace Your link is indeed the principal entry point for .Net developers interested in the .Net inplementation of Opentelemetry. However the projects described on that site help developers to generate telemetry data within an application. My question relates to capturing telemetry data downstream of an application. GO is the default language for this type of Opentelemetry infrastructure hence my difficulty in finding equivalent example C# code. I want to tightly integrate an Opentelemetry data collector with an existing C# application hence GO is not an option available to me.

Comment: Did you ever got this to work? I was looking for the same thing..